# How to get foreign key value using Serializer() class DRF

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have models `User` and `Role`. User model has foreign key `role` from model `Role` as show below.

**User Model**

```
class User(model.Model):

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
```

**Role Model**

```
class Role(models.Model):
    
    role_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, unique=True)
```

I wrote a serializer for model `User`.

```
class User(serializers.Serializer):

    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    role = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
```

I am using `APIView` to get the list of all the users. I want `get()` method of `APIVIew` to a return list of all the user with `role_name` instead of `role_id` like this -

```
[
    {
        "first_name":"Name",
        "role": "Admin"
    },
    {
        "first_name":"Name",
        "role": "Merchant"
    }
]
```

**views.py**

```
class ListUsers(APIView):

    def get(self, request, formate=None):

        admin_users = User.objects.all().values('first_name', 'role')


        return Response(admin_users)
```

My `ListUsers(APIView)` class returns the list like this -

```
[
    {
        "first_name":"Name",
        "role":1
    },
    {
        "first_name":"Name",
        "role":2
    }
]
```

I want my APIView to return list of users and each object should have `role_name` instead of `role_id`. I don't want to use `ModelSerializer`. Also, I have an `APIView()` class which create an object for model `User` and it uses the same serializer. I want a solution which would not affect create user functionality.

Comment: i am not sure I get it correctly. What would role be like during creation - ie when the client send the data ? a name or an ID ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you are not using your serializer. In order to use your serializer you have to use [ListAPIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview) instead of `APIView` and set its `serailizer_class` to the serializer you have implemented and set its `queryset` or implement its `get_queryset`. The list of lists is due to your code nesting the objects within a set:

```
    return Response({admin_users})
```

But as for returning role name instead of role id take look at [SlugRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) which is there specifically for your use case.

Comment: will it affect creating an object for `User` model as I am using same serializer for creating and listing user.

Comment: Yes. You have to use the role name when creatnig the user as well. Fortunately your `role_name` field is unique already so the lookup won't fail while creating the user.

Comment: So while creating a user I must send JSON like this - `{"first_name":"Name", "role_name", 1}` instead of  `{"first_name":"Name", "role", 1}`. Am I right?

Comment: I assume you mean `{"first_name":"Name", "role_name", "Merchant"}`. Yes if you are gonna name your slug related field as `role_name`.

Comment: So in MYSQL table `users` column `role_id` what exactly it will store in `role_id` as an integer field or `role_name` as `varchar()`?  Because as of now it stores `role_id` as an IntegerField.

Comment: The database-level data does not change even slightly. Here DRF is providing a layer that translates between role_name and role_id back and forth.

Comment: Can you tell me how to add `query_set` to the `SlugRelatedField()`.

Comment: from the docs: queryset: The queryset used for model instance lookups when validating the field input. Relationships must either set a queryset explicitly, or set read_only=True.

Comment: You have to set pass the queryset param based on the target model.

Comment: could you please update your answer to show how exactly I should write my `serializer` and `APIView`

Answer (score 0):

## First, Please do not use "id" as a field name, it is so wrong!

## Answer 1: easy way to do it:

```
class ListUsers(APIView):

    def get(self, request, formate=None):
        users = Userdrf.objects.all().values('first_name', 'role__role_name')
        return Response(users)
```

## The output

```
[
{'first_name': 'asd', 'role__role_name': 'admin'},
 {'first_name': 'asd', 'role__role_name': 'not_admin'}
]
```

## Answer 2: Another way is to connect the serializer to the view and modify it a bit with somthing like :

```
class User(serializers.Serializer):

    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    my_role = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
    fields = (
        'id',
        'my_role'
        )

def get_my_role(self, obj):
    
    return {
        'role': obj.user.role.role_name,
        }
```

BTW-

Answer (score 0):

Use the below serializer for getting the output you need.

This serializer can be used for creation too but instead of sending the role_id you have to send the role_name in the role field.

You did not specify what is the structure of your POST data so I am assuming it to be the same as the output.

```
class User(serializers.Serializer):

    first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, allow_blank=False)
    role = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, allow_blank=False)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        role = get_object_or_404(Role.objects.all(), role_name=validated_data['role'])
        user = User.objects.create(first_name=validated_data['first_name'], role=role)
        return user  

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        role = get_object_or_404(Role.objects.all(), role_name=validated_data['role'])
        instance.first_name = validated_data['first_name']
        instance.role = role
        instance.save()
        return instance

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        ret = {
            "first_name": instance.first_name,
            "role": instance.role.role_name,
        } 
        return ret
```